# Would I be a baritone or bass baritione if my vocal range is (C1)E1-A5?

Tags: voice

I can sing quite low and I can sing comfortably until about G3 which is kind of high to sing :/

Comment: See also http://music.stackexchange.com/q/8063/28

Answer (score 0):

It's more about the weight of your voice than the range.  I can squeak out some pretty high notes, but that doesn't make me a soprano!

Where are you happiest?  Where do you sound best?  Are you more likely to pick "Nessun Dorma" or "Old Man River" as a party piece (not necessarily in the original keys)?