# What am I given my vocal range?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I'm looking for help here, Am I a Baritone? My current vocal range is `A3` the lowest I can go, and a I can hit up to `F5`, If I go to `G5` I start getting a falsetto.

What am I?

Comment: If you are looking for your voice classification more information than your "range" is needed. You voice is classified based on things like your comfortable area, where your bridges(where you transition between your voices) and the texture of your voice.

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times in the past. Use the search... http://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+is+my+voice

Comment: See also http://music.stackexchange.com/q/8063/28

Answer (score 0):

If your last register change is at G5, you are likely a coloratura soprano.

If A3 is the lowest you can go as a male, you should wait for puberty or visit a doctor.  This is a note female altos are expected to reach convincingly, and most sopranos should at least be able to reach them.

I suspect that you don't realize that tenor notes are usually written an octave higher than sung.

At any rate, the notes at which you can make noises while untrained are of rather little relevance for determining the range you can control with a trained voice to the delight of an audience, and the latter is what determines your voice type.